# I can't get swarm installed

Tags: go-ethereum, swarm

I am following instructions in: http://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html and when i run this command : go get github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum , it shows me an error . 
Anyone has an idea why ?

Comment: No, but could you include the error logs or message?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have golang 1.8 installed.
It used to work with 1.6, but no longer. 
What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell the exact issue until we know ehat the error is. But If you are getting `import path does not begin with hostname` error. You need to update the go version to 1.8, although in [documentation](http://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) it is mentioned to use 1.7,

```
curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.7.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.7.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

but it doesn't work with version. Change above commands to :

```
curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.8.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.8.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

I have opened a pull request to update the documentation, but request not acknowledged yet.